# How to search for string with one variable position in the string?

Tags: search, awk, grep, full-text-search

I would like to find in a large file all lines, which contain a string and allow ONE character in my string to be different and still consider it a match.

For example I have this file:

```
>1 agctcaTATAAGtataagctagaagta
>2 gatgctagcgaagtaatgc
>3 atatagcgctagagccgtagta
>4 gctagcaTATCAGgatgtagtagta
...
```

and this string: `tataag`, so I get this output:

```
>1 agctcaTATAAGtataagctagaagta
>4 gctagcaTATCAGgatgtagtagta
```

Because line 1 matches directly and line 4 is a match for all but the letter `A` where it has a `C` instead.

Comment: Check out agrep: _search a file for a string or regular expression, with approximate matching capabilities_.

Comment: Please do add your efforts in form of code in your question and let us know then, it's highly encouraged on SO.

Comment: The man page of agrep looks very nice, but i failed to install it on my mac ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ # generate the different combinations
$ # assumes search term doesn't have regex metacharacters
$ echo 'tataag' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""} {orig=$0; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
                       { $i = "."; ORS=(i==NF)?"\n":"|"; print; $0=orig }}'
.ataag|t.taag|ta.aag|tat.ag|tata.g|tataa.

$ # pass it to grep as the regex to be used
$ echo 'tataag' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""} {orig=$0; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
                       { $i = "."; ORS=(i==NF)?"\n":"|"; print; $0=orig }}' | grep -iEf - ip.txt
>1 agctcaTATAAGtataagctagaagta
>4 gctagcaTATCAGgatgtagtagta
```

You can also make it stricter by using `[acgt]` instead of `.`

```
$ echo 'tataag' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""} {orig=$0; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
                       { $i = "[acgt]"; ORS=(i==NF)?"\n":"|"; print; $0=orig }}'
[acgt]ataag|t[acgt]taag|ta[acgt]aag|tat[acgt]ag|tata[acgt]g|tataa[acgt]
```

Answer (score 3):

To allow one char to be different:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    lgth = length(str)
    for (i=1; i<=lgth; i++) {
        head = esc(substr(str,1,i-1))
        tail = esc(substr(str,i+1))
        part = head "." tail
        reg  = (i>1 ? reg "|" : "") part
    }
    reg = "(" tolower(reg) ")"
    printf "Searching for string \"%s\"\n", str | "cat>&2"
    printf "Searching for regexp \"%s\"\n", reg | "cat>&2"
}
tolower($0) ~ reg

function esc(str) {
    gsub(/[^^\\]/,"[&]",str)
    gsub(/\^|\\/,"\\\\&",str)
    return str
}
```

.

```
$ awk -v str='tataag' -f tst.awk file
>1 agctcaTATAAGtataagctagaagta
>4 gctagcaTATCAGgatgtagtagta
Searching for string "tataag"
Searching for regexp "(.[a][t][a][a][g]|[t].[t][a][a][g]|[t][a].[a][a][g]|[t][a][t].[a][g]|[t][a][t][a].[g]|[t][a][t][a][a].)"
```

To allow one char to be missing:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    lgth = length(str)
    for (i=1; i<=lgth; i++) {
        head = esc(substr(str,1,i))
        tail = esc(substr(str,i+1))
        part = head "?" tail
        reg  = (i>1 ? reg "|" : "") part
    }
    reg = "(" tolower(reg) ")"
    printf "Searching for string \"%s\"\n", str | "cat>&2"
    printf "Searching for regexp \"%s\"\n", reg | "cat>&2"
}
tolower($0) ~ reg

function esc(str) {
    gsub(/[^^\\]/,"[&]",str)
    gsub(/\^|\\/,"\\\\&",str)
    return str
}
```

.

```
$ awk -v str='tataag' -f tst.awk file
>1 agctcaTATAAGtataagctagaagta
>3 atatagcgctagagccgtagta
Searching for string "tataag"
Searching for regexp "([t]?[a][t][a][a][g]|[t][a]?[t][a][a][g]|[t][a][t]?[a][a][g]|[t][a][t][a]?[a][g]|[t][a][t][a][a]?[g]|[t][a][t][a][a][g]?)"
```

All the escaping above is to ensure that your string gets treated as a literal string even if/when it contains regexp metacharacters.

You can remove the 2 print statements when you're done testing.